# Why does my chrome extension ask for history permissions?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest

In my `manifest.json` file, I have nothing explicitly listed for reading a user's history, however, this warning comes up when you try to install the extension.

### [image]

Here is my manifest file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "QueueTube for YouTube!", 
  "short_name": "QueueTube", 
  "description": "Search YouTube without stopping the video, and make your own playlists!",
  "version": "1.5",
  "author": "Dara Javaherian",

  "permissions": ["tabs", "*://*.youtube.com/*"],

  "background": {
    "persistent":true,
    "scripts": [
      "bg/socket.io.js",
      "bg/background.js"
    ]
  },
  "icons": {
    "128": "icons/youtube-128.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup/popup.html"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "spinner.gif"
  ],
  "content_scripts" : [{
    "matches" : 
      ["https://www.youtube.com/*",
      "http://www.youtube.com/*"],
    "js" : [
      "js/jquery.js",
      "js/inject.js"],
    "css" : ["styles/styles.css"]
  }]
}
```

Does anyone know why this permission is showing up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [standard warning](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings#warnings) for the `"tabs"` permission.

It allows you to query, and be notified of changes, to URLs of all tabs. This allows you to spy on the user's history in real time - even if you don't have access to the browser's own history log.

Note that `"tabs"` permission **is not required in most cases**. Providing access to URLs is basically the only reason to include it. You [can use most of the `tabs` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#intro) without it, and can get access to current tab without warning using [the `"activeTab"` permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab).

Answer (score 1):

> **Warnings and their triggers**
>
> > It can be surprising when adding a permission such as "tabs" results
> >     in the seemingly unrelated warning that the extension can access your
> >     browsing activity. The reason for the warning is that although the
> >     chrome.tabs API might be used only to open new tabs, it can also be
> >     used to see the URL that's associated with every newly opened tab
> >     (using their tabs.Tab objects)

Source: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings